# Android - Encode info in image pixels

Tags: android, image-processing

I have an image processing app, and I have to remember which photos have already been processed. In order to do so, I store an EXIF metadata in the image file, but if the user decides to send the image over WhatsApp, etc, the metadata is lost, so I can't rely on this.

So I though a solution would be to use some pixels in the image to remember if the photo was processed or not, something like if that pixel has that color and that other that other color, then it was processed.

I have tried to do so, but if the image gets scaled down, then my approach won't work.

Any ideas on how to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quite complicated topic and there's no silver bullet that'll help you. One pitfall is the fact that most image compression algorithms try to throw away data our eyes cannot see, and your watermarking algorithm would then have to make modifications that are visible to the human eye, which is probably not what you want.

Another thing to note is whatever you do, if you go with the route of storing data using pixels, you're going to have false positives.

What you could do, since your app already does image processing, is to embed your application's logo as a watermark into the image somewhere. Then you can attempt to find distinct features of your logo in the image, which is admittedly not very easy, but neither is the problem.

Again, this problem is already quite complicated so I'm sorry if this answer isn't adequate.